# Greater Than or equal into String Variables

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
{
    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);

    c.setBackground(getBackground());
    int modelRow = convertRowIndexToModel(row);
    String Value = (String)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 7);
    if (Value <= 30) c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    return c;
}
```

This is my codes. In the if Statement I want to compare it if its greater than or equal to 30.

Comment: There is no need to override `prepareRenderer`, you should simply supply a custom renderer capable of achieving your needs or using the highlighting support from something like SwingLabs, SwingX library (and `JXTable`)

Comment: Sorry missed that...

Comment: Sorry mad can you give an example?

Comment: [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: @Xyryle Buen 1. use `prepareRenderer`  2. you have to put `number` to `model` or remove casting to `String` -  `String Value = (String)` 3. and override `getColumnClass` (many times here about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-):

```
    int Value = Integer.parseInt((String)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 7));
//  ^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                          ^
    if (Value <= 30) c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
```

...or possibly [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-) (with `long Value`) if there's a possibility that the value will exceed the capacity of an `int`.

---

Side note: Obviously, you can do whatever you like in your own code, but staying close to common conventions is useful, particularly when asking for help. With Java conventions, local variables don't start with uppercase characters (e.g., `value` rather than `Value`).

Comment: @XyryleBuen: Then you'll need to add a `null` check, as `(String)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 7)` is returning `null`.

Comment: sorry sorry i was fix it already by changing the datatype in the database

Comment: by the way how can i check if its null?

Comment: @XyryleBuen: `thingToCheck == null`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder `I think you're looking for` - put number to model rathen than, but maybe there is number `String value - `(String)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 7);`, nobody knows, just another reason for why is(could be) MCVE/SSCCE standard here:-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you me a code that will check if its null base on my code above. Please

Comment: @XyryleBuen: I think you need to step back from your current task and work through some basic Java tutorials. But basically: `String valueString = (String)getModel().getValueAt(modelRow, 7); if (valueString == null) { /* do what you should do when it's null */ } else { value = Integer.parseInt(valueString); /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You can compare like-

```
if(Integer.parseInt(value)<=30){c.setBackground(Color.Green)}
```